# Guid as PK of Sql Server Table

Tags: sql-server, database-design, uuid

By default, a SQLServer table clustered index is the PK. If I define that:

- such key is a GUID and
- I will generate at random a.k.a `Guid.NewGuid()` and
- forget to set the clustered index to a more meaningful column

will SQLServer reorder the pages as a new record enters the table or will it just "ignore" the clustered part of the index?

Answer (score 0):

I think you got it reversed: by default, the PK is also the clustered index. You must choose the data type and what columns to include in the PK. SQL Server won't set a default PK for you. Without a PK, a table is a heap.

Using GUID as a PK is bad practice. You will cause unnecessary page splits upon `INSERT`. If the data does not have a natural key, use an `IDENTITY` column instead.

Answer (score 0):

So you create PK and it defaults to a clustered.  You change it to a non clustered index.   What makes you think there is a clustered index hanging around?   There is no clustered part to the index if you changed it to a non clustered.

Comment: Where is the mention of Azure?   Even with Azure you think it would be required and ignored if you had duplicate non clustered index?